# BeautifulSoup shows "'NoneType' object is not callable" when using find_all

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Basically i want to scrape the href from a tag where class="something". But i have encountered an error saying `'NoneType' object is not callable` here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(thr_data) # where thr_data is the response.read()
images = soup.find_all("a", {"class" : "something"})

 for link in images:
      cr_link = link['href']
```

and the html is like this `<a ... href="url" class="something"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was apparently with the BeautifulSoup version. I had to get the newest version by installing `python-bs4` . And then import the module `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

I use to get the same error when I use **find_all**. That's why I always use **findAll**. I don't know why, may be in some upgraded version of Beautifulsoup works for both of these!